# How to use SQL to parse several numbers out of a single field with tokens

Tags: sql, string, parsing

What I want to do is simple to describe I have strings:

```
string1 = '30-3/8"'
String2 = '2-1/16'
String3 = '9" and 6-1/2"'
String4 = '3-3/4 x 3-1/2"'
```

What I need to do with SQL is convert the string to a decimal equivalent in inches.  Need result of Number left of “–” + (left of “/”/ right of “/”).  Thought this would be easier using:

```
SUBSTR([field], int, int) and CHARINDEX(string, [field])
```

but I haven't figured it out and quite stuck, need to do this inside an application interpreting SQL in the language of SAS .  Any help much appreciated of course.   Here is the approach I've taken but I can't but wonder if there is a better way:

```
CASE  

 WHEN ([Shaft Dia.]  like '_' ) THEN CAST( [Shaft Dia.] as FLOAT) 
 WHEN ([Shaft Dia.]  like '_"' ) THEN CAST( [Shaft Dia.] as FLOAT)
 WHEN ([Shaft Dia.]  like '%mm' ) THEN (CAST( [Shaft Dia.] as FLOAT)* 0.039370)
 WHEN ([Shaft Dia.]  like '%-%/%' ) THEN (CAST(LEFT(RIGHT([Shaft Dia.], Len([Shaft Dia.]) - Charindex('-',[Shaft Dia.])), CHARINDEX('/',[Shaft Dia.]) - CHARINDEX('-',[Shaft Dia.]) - 1)  as FLOAT)  / RIGHT([Shaft Dia.],(LEN([Shaft Dia.]) - (CHARINDEX('/',[Shaft Dia.]))))) + SUBSTRING([Shaft Dia.], 0, CHARINDEX('-', [Shaft Dia.]))
 WHEN ([Shaft Dia.]  like '% %/%"' ) THEN (CAST(LEFT(RIGHT([Shaft Dia.], Len([Shaft Dia.]) - Charindex(' ',[Shaft Dia.])), CHARINDEX('/',[Shaft Dia.]) - CHARINDEX(' ',[Shaft Dia.]) - 1)  as FLOAT)  / RIGHT([Shaft Dia.],(LEN([Shaft Dia.]) - (CHARINDEX('/',[Shaft Dia.]))))) + SUBSTRING([Shaft Dia.], 0, CHARINDEX(' ', [Shaft Dia.]))

 WHEN ([Shaft Dia.]  like '%/%' ) THEN CAST (SUBSTRING([Shaft Dia.], 0, CHARINDEX('/', [Shaft Dia.])) as FLOAT) / RIGHT([Shaft Dia.] ,(LEN([Shaft Dia.] ) - (CHARINDEX('/',[Shaft Dia.] ))))


 END
```

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: also please tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: Those are promising functions.  What was your attempt and what went wrong?

Comment: output is number representing inches so '1- 1/2' should be the number of 1.5

Comment: @ChrisLong what version of SQL Server are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Create Some Sample Data
Declare @Table table (ID int,String varchar(250))
Insert into @Table values (1,'30-3/8"'),(2,'2-1/16'),(3,'9" and 6-1/2"'),(4,'3-3/4 x 3-1/2"')

-- Create a Mapping Table
Declare @Map Table (Seq int,StrFrom varchar(50),StrTo varchar(50))
Insert Into @Map values
(1,'  ',' '),
(1,' - ','+'),
(1,'- ','+'),
(1,' -','+'),
(1,'-','+'),
(1,' /','/'),
(1,'/ ','/'),
(9,'+0.','.')

-- Extend Mapping Table with Generated Common Fractions
Declare @Num table (Num int);Insert Into @Num values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24)
Declare @Den table (Den int);Insert Into @Den values (2),(4),(8),(16),(32),(64)
Insert Into @Map Select Seq=2,StrFrom=concat(Num,'/',Den),StrTo  =cast((Num+.0)/Den as decimal(11,6)) From @Num A Join @Den B on 1=1 Where (Num+.0)/Den <1

-- Process Data 1) Convert to Data to XML   2) Global Search & Replace from Map Table  3) Convert back to XML
Declare @String varchar(max),@XML XML
Select  @String = cast((Select * From @Table for XML RAW) as varchar(max))
Select  @String = replace(@String,strFrom,strTo) from @Map Order by Seq
Select  @XML    = Convert(XML,@String)

-- Generate Final Results
Select A.ID
      ,A.String
      ,B.Converted
 From @Table A
 Join (
        Select ID        = Tbl.Col.value('@ID', 'int'),  
               Converted = Replace(Tbl.Col.value('@String', 'varchar(250)'),'"','')
         From  @xml.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col)  
      ) B on A.ID=B.ID
```

Returns

```
ID  String          Converted
1   30-3/8"         30.375000
2   2-1/16          2.062500
3   9" and 6-1/2"   9 and 6.500000
4   3-3/4 x 3-1/2"  3.750000 x 3.500000
```

> **I'm not clear on how you want to handle IDs 3 & 4... AND/X**

I should add, my Mapping Table is an actual table, but I gave you a scaled down version for demonstrative purposes

I should also add, that if you'd rather a scalar function, the XML can be removed.